# Elasticsearch wildcard search on multiple fields

Tags: java, elasticsearch, filter, wildcard, elk

Im building a filter function and what I want is a wildcard filter. If value is "roj", all records in any field containing "roj" should be displayed.

How to implement this?

Here's my query,

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "Project_error"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "api_name": {
              "wildcard": "*roj*"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "error_Code": {
              "wildcard": "*roj*"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Java code

```
BoolQueryBuilder bqb = new BoolQueryBuilder();
bqb.must(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("Project_error"))

if(!filter.isEmpty()) {
   bqb.filter(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery(fields[0],"*"+filter+"*"));
   bqb.must(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery(fields[1],"*"+filter+"*"));
   ...
}

searchSourceBuilder.query(bqb);
```

This script displays data only if both field contains "roj", which not correct.

Comment: Use should (OR) instead of must (AND). https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Comment: I should listened to you. ```AND``` operator works! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Below query you can achieve the result.

```
GET <index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*roj*",
            "fields":["field_1", "field_2"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you want apply your query term in all fields remove the fields attributes in the above query.!!!

Comment: ```query_string``` it only search per prefix, not the whole prefix/phrase of string.